# Staying Logged On

Tags: discussion, login

I have vague memories of Stack Overflow having a feature that allowed lazy people like me to stay logged on.  Recently, I noticed that I have to log on every time I launch my browser.  Also, the login page does not appear to have anything that allows me to choose to stay logged on.

Is this a recent change or am I simple doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: Was the massive block of white really necessary?  That aside, though, what version of IE is that?

Comment: It's IE 11.  However, the same thing happens on Firefox and Chrome.  I normally use Firefox.  The change in behaviour seemed to start this week.

Comment: Cleaned up whitespace.

Comment: @DanBracuk Not that familiar with IE; do you have extensions installed(as in I don't know if IE has them).  It seems you have one installed.. the toolbar, I mean; .. though either way, I'm not experiencing your issue.

Comment: Maybe you've turned into one of paranoid people (explicitly or mistakenly) and configured your browser to clear cookies/history on restart?

Comment: Clearing cookies would explain having to log in each time.  It would not explain the lack of a checkbox enabling me to opt to stay logged in.  Regarding add-ins, there are three McAffee ones, Skype Clear to Call settings, Messenger Companion, OneNote Linked Notes, Blog in this Windows Live Writer, and Messenger Companion enabled in IE.